# Use Cloud Pub/Sub to trigger sending of email

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm trying to figure out how to use Cloud Pub/Sub to trigger the sending of an email when a file is added to a storage bucket.

Currently using PHP72 in Google App Engine standard environment.  First I created a Topic that creates a message when a file is added to the storage bucket.  Then I created a Pull subscription which reads the message. I can view the messages in the GCP console, but what I would like to happen is that I want to be notified by email, preferably with a copy of the file added to the email as an attachment.  Is this possible?  I tried looking for a solution or tutorial but came up empty.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement the send mail login in a cloud function which will be triggered by Pub/Sub (Node.js,Python,Go).

[Using Pub/Sub to trigger a Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/tut-pub-sub)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a pull subscription, you should probably use a [push subscription with App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscriber#push-subscription), combined with one of the third party mail services such as [Send Grid or MailJet](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/sending-messages).

The [upload of an object to GCS triggers a message to be sent to the topic](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications), and the push subscription delivers that message to App Engine.

Unfortunately, there aren't any full tutorials asking for exactly what you want, but hopefully this helps. Feel free to request a community tutorial for this by filing an issue on the [GCP community toturial repo](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/community/issues).